# How can make jquery ajax controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, ajax, jquery, magento-2.0.7

I am not able to find correct approaches to done this work. I found some resources but there they guys are using model files also but they didn't explain about that files. My codes are below

**Controller file**

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;



class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param NewsFactory $modelNewsFactory
 */



public function __construct(
        Context                                             $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory    $resultJsonFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory            = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


   public function execute() {


    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax())) 
    {

        $test=Array
        (
            'Firstname' => 'What is your firstname',
            'Email' => 'What is your emailId',
            'Lastname' => 'What is your lastname',
            'Country' => 'Your Country'
        );
        return $result->setData($test);
    }
}
}
```

**Template file**

```
data = jQuery(this).serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
               showLoader: true,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "modulename/index/index", 
                data: "label=" + abc,
                success: function (result) { jQuery('#result').html(result); },
                error: function (error) { alert(error); }
```

Please somebody guide me

Comment: Your Ajax cannot work?

Comment: Then how it will work. If you know then please guide me

Comment: what to you receive in response in your javascript ?

Comment: Error block has been working